# Sony Vaio Hard Drive replacement won't boot

Tags: windows-vista, sata, sony-vaio

I'm working on a Sony Vaio VGN-CR120e.

I've cloned the original SATA 1.5 drive with Norton Ghost on to 2 new hard drives, the second of which is a Seagate 7200.4 320Gb 7200 RPM, with the jumper set to limit to SATA 1.5. (The first drive is a WD Scorpio Black 320Gb 7200RMP, which has no SATA 1.5 override support).

Neither of the cloned drives will boot - I immediately get a BlackSOD saying:

"Windows failed to start blah blah blah"

"File \Windows\system32\winload.exe"

"Status: 0xc000000e"

"Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt."

I've done this hundreds of times on other PC's, and this is the first time I've encountered such an error.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice on how to proceeed, as I would rather not reinstall Vista unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I seem to have managed to answer my own question.

The bootloader for Vista was buggered.  I only had a Windows 7 disk available, so I booted with it.  I selected Repair Windows Installation, and allowed it to automatically repair the startup options.

It was a quick 5 second fix for 7 hours of head scratching.

More info on this solution is found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392